# how to monitor window process using java?

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, process, java-native-interface

how can I get  a  call back when the process in the windows tasklist is killed using java?how can I  monitor the  event? i want to realize that if process is killed then start auto?

great thanks！

Comment: I've heard that you can use WMI for this and perhaps one of the libraries that provide a Java-COM bridge such as JACOB.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you for your advice.Is there any sample?

Comment: By "windows tasklist" do you mean Windows OS processes?  If so, please add a "windows" tag to the question.  This is more about monitoring processes on Windows than it is about Java.

Comment: @OldPro yes,I mean windows os processes,thank you for your advice

Comment: This process is a your java process?

Comment: @dash1e not java process.the windows os processes in window Task Manager

Comment: I have not done this myself, but I've heard that by using VMI, you would listen to events which *may* be a more elegant solution than polling as suggested by @dash1e.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you can allocate a thread that every N seconds call the external process

```
tasklist /v
```

maybe with a filter on your Window Title or program name.

To launch `tasklist` from java you can do

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist /v");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

and then read the `BufferedReader` and check for your process.

Remember to terminate every time the process in the right way.

Comment: great thanks! how to terminate the process? now everytime it produce a tasklist.exe window os process.

Comment: There are many questions on this topic. For example read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns

Comment: Read all this article: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html