# Alternatives to Runtime and ProcessBuilder (Java)

Tags: java, runtime, processbuilder

I am interested if anyone has an idea on how to run unix commands without using runtime or ProcessBuilder in a java application

Answer (score 5):

Well you can use [DefaultExecutor](http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecutor.html) from [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) library to execute commands but it internally uses `java.lang.Runtime` and `java.lang.Process`.

I would suggest you to use this library over Runtime because Apache Command Execution APIs are more sophisticated, and provide all and more features than Java Runtime. It also handles exit Values.

Comment: Does it handle the hang issue as detailed in this comment - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5483880/537503 ?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few possible ways; but I can't call any of them desirable without understanding your motivation.

For example, write a program in C or Perl or whatever language and have it listen on a socket.  Your java program can then connect to the socket and send a message with the name of the program to spawn, arguments etc. The receiver program can go ahead and spawn this.

Comment: right so the idea for this is to create java server app which responds to basic commands like ls, pwd, cd etc.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to execute Unix commands:

1. You can use `java.lang.Runtime` and `java.lang.Process`
2. You can use JNI/JNA to access shared libraries. So you could use this to access the OS level commands to create a process (`system()` and `exec*()` on Unix).

The second approach isn't recommended: It's hard to get right and eventually, you will end up with something that has exactly the same functionality as `Runtime.exec()`

If you only need the *functionality*, then you can implement the commands again in Java. For example, to implement `ls`, use `File.listFiles()`