# Java process never stops

Tags: java, process

I am trying to execute a process from my Java application, when I execute this process from the console it works right, but when I do getRuntime().exec() it starts but never ends, no exceptions, no exit values.
The process I am trying to execute is pdftops.exe, an app that converts PDF files to PostScript.
When I try to convert small files (executing from Java) it works OK, the problem is converting larger PDFs which may take longer (from 20 to 60 seconds). I think the problem may be that the execution time is too long.
Here is the piece of code that calls the program (the command line is simplified, the input.pdf and output.ps are placed in a folder inside my home directory, and pdftops.exe is placed in Desktop):

```
String comando = "pdftops.exe input.pdf output.ps";
System.out.println("Executing "+comando);
try {
    Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);            
    pr.waitFor();      
    System.out.println("Finished");
}
catch (IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch(InterruptedException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

EDIT: Reading the process' ErrorStream solves the problem:

```
try {
    System.out.println(comando);
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);            

    String line;

    InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream ();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stderr));

    line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null && ! line.trim().equals("--EOF--")) {
        System.out.println ("Stdout: " + line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
}
catch (IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do you ever see `Finished` or any other output in the console?

Comment: No, it only writes the first println ("Executing...")

Comment: what exit value are you getting from `waitFor()`?

Comment: so it is still running. what do you want exactly?

Comment: could it be that the .exe is expecting some user feedback on standard input or in a GUI that cannot be displayed?

Comment: I can see at least one typo that would prevent your code from compiling. Please show us your actual code, and not some approximation thereof.

Comment: waitFor() never returns. The process never ends. Also, it does not expect any input from the user. It writes to the output stream though, MadProgrammer may be right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [process.waitFor() never returns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not immediate answer to your question, but might be useful to capture the error/output stream of the process so you know what is going on there (assuming it produces something).

With java 7 you can use pretty handy [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28boolean%29) and merge your error stream into the output one ...

Could it be waiting for some input for example?

Comment: In fact, you're probably closer to the answer then you think.  Many processes won't exit until they're output streams have been flushed.  Read the contents of the process's `InputStream`.

Comment: Right, that sounds likely!

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, if I read the ErrorStream of the process it finishes, thanks. I will update the question to put the code that works.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) (similar to what Jan said earlier) and if your using Java 5 at least something like below might tell you what the error is if any...

```
public void execute () throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("pdftops.exe", "input.pdf", "output.ps");

    Process process = pb.start();

    System.out.println("Error stream:");
    InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
    printStream(errorStream);

    process.waitFor();

    System.out.println("Output stream:");
    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    printStream(inputStream);
}

private void printStream (InputStream stream) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use ProcessBuilder but I get error=2, it says it cannot run program "pdftops.exe". I've set the directory with pb.directory(new File(path_to_directory));

Comment: what are you using for path_to_directory, smells to me like your using an invalid directory...

Comment: new File("C:\\Users\\Joel\\Downloads\\xpdfbin-win-3.03\\bin32\\")

Comment: Strange... But you might want to try `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\Joel\\Downloads\\xpdfbin-win-3.03\\bin32\\pdftops.exe", "input.pdf", "output.ps");` instead and don't use the `pb.directory` command at all. Its suppose to set the working directory however seems like it doesn't for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the java documentation you will find this :

```
waitFor : Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated. This method returns immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess exits.
Returns: the exit value of the subprocess represented by this Process object. By convention, the value 0 indicates normal termination.
Throws: InterruptedException - if the current thread is interrupted by another thread while it is waiting, then the wait is ended and an InterruptedException is thrown.
```

My guess is that for big files it runs into a time conundrum which befuddles the execution . Probably you can here check the finished state of the executing process like this :

```
  if(Process.exitValue()==0)
  break;
```

This will make sure that once your execution is over, an infinite or over aggressive loop will not be an end result of the execution .

Comment: `exitValue()` will throw an `IllegalThreadStateException` if you call it before it's done. That's why he's using `waitFor()`

Comment: I understand that, but what if its applied after the catch blocks, that ought to find out if the process execution is over or not .

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you. But it won't help anyway, because his process never terminates.

Comment: yes that sounds about right, probably then process builder will be much more handy here .