# making process wait

Tags: java

I am using the following code to run terminal commands through my command prompt

```
String[] command =
        {
      "zsh"
          };
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), b)).start();
                new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), b)).start();
                PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
                stdin.println("source ./taxenv/bin/activate");
                stdin.println("python runner.py");
                stdin.close();
                int returnCode = 0;
                try {
                    returnCode = p.waitFor();

                    String path2 = b + "/logs.txt"; // I am getting b value passed in from gc.jsp
                    if(new File(path2).exists())
                    {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path2));

                            while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                                {
                                    content= content + line1 +"<br>";
                                }
                            reader.close();
                            request.setAttribute("logs", content);

                            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("gc.jsp");
                            rd.forward(request, response);


                }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                    System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode +b);
    }               
    class SyncPipe implements Runnable
    {

    public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, String c) {
          istrm_ = istrm;
          b_ = c;
      }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void run() {
          try
          {
              final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            for(int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; )
              {
                   str = str + IOUtils.toString(istrm_, "UTF-8") + b_;
              }
            System.out.println(str);

            String location = b_ + "/" + "logs.txt";
            File file = new File(location);
            if(!file.exists())
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(str);
            bw.close();


          }

          catch (Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      private final InputStream istrm_;
      private final String b_;
```

When I run this code I expect it to be re directed to gc.jsp, but it displays as follows

[image]

Now, When I refresh the above page I am getting output as expected, shown below.

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I solve this?

=============================EDIT==========================

I've added

```
bw.close() //Closing bufferedwriter
fw.close() //Closing file writer
```

still of no use.

Now, I've added

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

This works fine for small files, so basically the problem is that code from the line

> String path2 = b + "/logs.txt";

must wait for the process p to complete.

How do I do this?

Comment: Are exceptions preventing the forward?

Comment: I have no idea..when I refresh page I am getting the output

Comment: The console log is also empty..I guess there is some logical error I need to process the if loop only after the completion of returnCode = p.waitFor(); but how do I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns

Comment: Try While(p.waitFor() == 0) {}

Comment: @ray I've tried p.waitfor() == 0, it doesn't work.

Comment: You're launching a zsh process and sending it two commands to run. Don't you need to send it an `exit` command (or ^D) to get it to exit? (BTW, the docs on Process recommend buffering its I/O streams.)

Comment: Yes, I did exit it. But I've not included those lines here as it is of not much importance here.

Comment: As i see it, you try to read the logs.txt file before the SyncPipe wrote the file. You can solve this with a barrier.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem..what barrier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you try reading the files before your `SyncPipe`s finished writing to your files. You can solve this by waiting until all threads are finished (`join()`)

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
Thread threadError = new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), b));
Thread threadInput = new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), b));

threadError.start();
threadInput.start();

/* writing to process */

// wait until your process finished
p.waitFor();

// wait for both threads until they finished writing to files
threadError.join();
threadInput.join();

// read your files
```

**Description**: Your SyncPipe thread will stop when the Input/ErrorStream is closed because the process `p` stopped. Then it will write everything to file and close the files appropriately. After that the Thread is stopped correctly.

The `join` method tells your main thread (the caller of `join`) to wait until the thread is stopped (the callee of join, e.g. threadError). `waitFor` is somewhat equivalent to `join`.

After that you can say for sure that all threads are stopped correctly (`p`, `threadError` and `threadInput`) and therefore all files are written to disk. Now you can read them.