# Groovy execute process hangs

Tags: groovy, process

In a groovy script I execute an application on linux and windows with:

```
def proc = command.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput( System.out, System.err)
    println "here"
proc.waitFor()
    println "never here"
```

but the waitFor() call never returns. The strange thing is that it only happens on linux.

Based on this:
[process.waitFor() never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns)

it could be caused by not reading from the appropriate streams. But as you can see I consume both System.out, System.err. Are there other streams that could be consumed?

Comment: what process are you running?

Comment: This consumeProcessOutput line just killed 2 birds with 1 stone! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar problem and the process being run was only hanging on `jenkins` CI server. It was a `plutil` command and `consumeProcessOutputStream` method was used.

Since there I use `ProcessBuilder` to construct and run processes.

```
def processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder('some command')
processBuilder.directory(new File('some dir')).environment().putAll([:])
processBuilder.redirectOutput(new File('out'))
processBuilder.redirectError(new File('err'))
```

Unfortunately no idea what causes Your problem.