# process wait for does not return

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

I am having a similar issue as in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns) 
The solution they propose is to attach a buffered reader. This is not what I want - I am not interested in the output the process produces. If I run the program with buffered reader, reading from output takes 90% of the execution time and I would want to avoid this bottleneck. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't read the output and the buffer is full the program won't return. Simple as that.

Comment: I know that... I want to have a workaround so that my program is not delayed and that the program will return. There must be a way to accomplish this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'workaround' is to consume the process's output. You don't have any choice about that unless you can arrange for it to be redirected to the null device. If you don't care what it is, use an input stream, not a reader, to save the character conversion overhead. NB at present *not* consuming the output is taking 100% of the execution time ...