# Execute spark-submit programmatically from java

Tags: java, apache-spark, runtime.exec

I am trying to execute it via:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(spark_cmd);
```

with no luck. The command ran via shell starts my application which succeeds. Running it via exec start a process which dies shortly after and does nothing.
When I try

```
process.waitFor();
```

it hangs and waits forever. Real magic begins when I try to read something from the process:

```
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream());
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

To do so I start a thread that reads from the stream in a while loop:

```
class ReadingThread extends Thread {

   BufferedReader reader;
   Wontekk(BufferedReader reader) {
      this.reader = reader;

   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      String line;
      try {
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
         }
      } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Application starts, does some stuff, and hangs. When I abort my application, spark application wakes up (??????????) and completes remaining work. Does anyone have reasonable explanation of what is happening?

thanks

Comment: please look at my answer. Which worked for us..

Comment: was it helpful?

Answer (score 4):

You can send a spark job as `spark-submit` with the help of Java's `SparkLauncher` class.  Check it out at

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html

Comment: : are there any other options as well ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is Spark launcher as told by @Sandeep Purohit

I'd offer shell script approach with nohup command to submit job like this...

> This worked for me incase of mapreduce executions... same way you can
>   try for spark background jobs as well.

Have a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup
"`nohup spark-submit <parameters> 2>&1 < /dev/null &`"

When ever, you get messages then you can poll that event and call this shell script. Below is the code snippet to do this...

```
/**
     * This method is to spark submit
     * <pre> You can call spark-submit or mapreduce job on the fly like this.. by calling shell script... </pre>
     * @param commandToExecute String 
     */
    public static Boolean executeCommand(final String commandToExecute) {
        try {
            final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            // LOG.info("process command -- " + commandToExecute);
            final String[] arr = { "/bin/sh", "-c", commandToExecute};
            final Process proc = rt.exec(arr);
            // LOG.info("process started ");
            final int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            LOG.trace(" commandToExecute exited with code: " + exitVal);
            proc.destroy();

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception occurred while Launching process : " + e.getMessage());
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
             return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
```

Moreover to debug

```
ps -aef | grep "your pid or process name"
```

Below command will list the open files opened by the process..

```
lsof -p <your process id >
```

Also, have a look at [process.waitFor() never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns)