# How to use java api to send hbase shell command directly like jdbc?

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix

How to use java api to send **hbase shell command** directly **like jdbc**?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // get Connection to connect hbase
    Connection conn = ....;
    // hbase shell command
    String cmd = "get 't1','r1'";

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(cmd);
    while(rs.next()) {
       ...
    }
}
```

if there is no java api for this, is there another way to achieve the goal?

Comment: If the Jar is executed directly on one of Hbase cluster's node, you can execute any **hbase shell command** using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command). I used it in a Java program where i needed to use the complete bulkload tool. If you want I give you the snippet code.

Comment: I've done something similar in JRuby (which is what the Hbase shell is written in). Otherwise, there is definitely an Hbase java client API, so I'm not sure I understand why passing raw shell commands is a good idea

Comment: Have you researched the use of the Java Hbase API?  http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_HBase_Table_with_Java_API.php

Comment: @cricket007 : yes above link is java hbase client which is common practise... but user wanted "java api to send hbase shell command directly " which is not! @ Guo, you can use hbase java client which is flexible way of doing things in a right way.

Answer (score 3):

#### Please note that, Phoenix can execute queries in jdbc style... If you want to execute get commands then you can use Hbase java client api directly. Its not common practice to execute from java through shell.

If you still want to do it from java prepare gets or list of commands in a text file and using `RunTime.execute` you can execute `hbase shell <yourhbaseshelllcommands.txt>`

see my [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866640/execute-spark-submit-programmatically-from-java/39451973#39451973) or [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451176/trigger-a-spark-job-whenever-an-event-occurs/39451487#39451487) this to do that. I have done that for spark submit and mapreduce jobs. you can use the same method for your hbase shell execution which was described above.

> another way to achieve the goal

To access Hbase in SQL way you can use Phoenix. 
- https://phoenix.apache.org/faq.html
-    [see this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/3030214/big-data/open-source-java-projects-apache-phoenix.html)

Also you can check with Impala or hive.

## JDBC Client Driver :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class PhoenixExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create variables
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {
            // Connect to the database
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:localhost");

            // Create a JDBC statement
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            // Execute our statements
            statement.executeUpdate("create table javatest (mykey integer not null primary key, mycolumn varchar)");
            statement.executeUpdate("upsert into javatest values (1,'Hello')");
            statement.executeUpdate("upsert into javatest values (2,'Java Application')");
            connection.commit();

            // Query for table
            ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from javatest");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("Table Values");
            while(rs.next()) {
                Integer myKey = rs.getInt(1);
                String myColumn = rs.getString(2);
                System.out.println("\tRow: " + myKey + " = " + myColumn);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(ps != null) {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {}
            }
            if(rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {}
            }
            if(statement != null) {
                try {
                    statement.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {}
            }
            if(connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using maven below are dependencies...

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0-HBase-1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Isn't this assuming the Phoenix server is installed? The question seems to want to send Hbase shell commands, which is definitely possible given the Hbase client is installed and configured.

Comment: user specified that he wanted to access through/like jdbc.thats why I suggested phoenix.

Comment: I suppose OP is confused that JDBC doesn't typically send arbitrary shell commands. Mostly just SQL

Comment: @RamPrasadG Thank you for your reply! But I want to send **hbase shell command** directly, not **SQL**.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks! You are right! I want to send **hbase shell command** directly, not **SQL**.

Comment: Please note that, Phoenix can execute queries in jdbc style... If you want to execute get commands then you can use Hbase java client api directly. Its  not common practice to execute from shell. if you still want to do it from java prepare gets or list of commands in a text file and using `RunTime.execute`  you can execute `hbase shell <yourhbaseshelllcommands.txt>`

Comment: see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866640/execute-spark-submit-programmatically-from-java/39451973#39451973) to do that. I have done that for spark submit and mapreduce jobs. you can use the same method for your hbase shell execution which was described above.

Comment: updated my answer.@cricket_007 you can demonstrate your jruby approach which can be useful for the user