# How does HBase internally analysis "hbase shell command"?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, jruby

Suppose, I run `get 't1','r1'` command in hbase shell, How does **HBase internally** analysis and execute this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a jruby script. which was defined under set of shell commands.

> I am quoting here java HashMap as an example for better
>   understanding..

- while inserting , Your rowkey is just like key in java HashMap which will be stored in one of the region server(in hash map case these are buckets which are uniformly distributed..)
- While getting back the row, it uses rowkey and it will locate particular region server and brings the value for that, from the table you mentioned.[image: example of hashmap like...]

> That's the reason while dealing with hbase rowkey design should be perfect (with salting technique , using hashing algorithm for ex: [mumur hash](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/HashingExplained)) and it should be uniformly distributed across region servers to  prevent hot spotting...
>   [image]

For more details, have a look at [get.rb](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-shell/src/main/ruby/shell/commands/get.rb)

```
module Shell
  module Commands
    class Get < Command
      def help
        return <<-EOF
Get row or cell contents; pass table name, row, and optionally
a dictionary of column(s), timestamp, timerange and versions. Examples:
  hbase> get 'ns1:t1', 'r1'
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1'
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {TIMERANGE => [ts1, ts2]}
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {COLUMN => 'c1'}
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {COLUMN => ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']}
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {COLUMN => 'c1', TIMESTAMP => ts1}
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {COLUMN => 'c1', TIMERANGE => [ts1, ts2], VERSIONS => 4}
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {COLUMN => 'c1', TIMESTAMP => ts1, VERSIONS => 4}
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {FILTER => "ValueFilter(=, 'binary:abc')"}
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', 'c1'
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', 'c1', 'c2'
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', ['c1', 'c2']
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {COLUMN => 'c1', ATTRIBUTES => {'mykey'=>'myvalue'}}
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {COLUMN => 'c1', AUTHORIZATIONS => ['PRIVATE','SECRET']}
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {CONSISTENCY => 'TIMELINE'}
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1', {CONSISTENCY => 'TIMELINE', REGION_REPLICA_ID => 1}
Besides the default 'toStringBinary' format, 'get' also supports custom formatting by
column.  A user can define a FORMATTER by adding it to the column name in the get
specification.  The FORMATTER can be stipulated: 
 1. either as a org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes method name (e.g, toInt, toString)
 2. or as a custom class followed by method name: e.g. 'c(MyFormatterClass).format'.
Example formatting cf:qualifier1 and cf:qualifier2 both as Integers: 
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1' {COLUMN => ['cf:qualifier1:toInt',
    'cf:qualifier2:c(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes).toInt'] } 
Note that you can specify a FORMATTER by column only (cf:qualifier).  You cannot specify
a FORMATTER for all columns of a column family.

The same commands also can be run on a reference to a table (obtained via get_table or
create_table). Suppose you had a reference t to table 't1', the corresponding commands
would be:
  hbase> t.get 'r1'
  hbase> t.get 'r1', {TIMERANGE => [ts1, ts2]}
  hbase> t.get 'r1', {COLUMN => 'c1'}
  hbase> t.get 'r1', {COLUMN => ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']}
  hbase> t.get 'r1', {COLUMN => 'c1', TIMESTAMP => ts1}
  hbase> t.get 'r1', {COLUMN => 'c1', TIMERANGE => [ts1, ts2], VERSIONS => 4}
  hbase> t.get 'r1', {COLUMN => 'c1', TIMESTAMP => ts1, VERSIONS => 4}
  hbase> t.get 'r1', {FILTER => "ValueFilter(=, 'binary:abc')"}
  hbase> t.get 'r1', 'c1'
  hbase> t.get 'r1', 'c1', 'c2'
  hbase> t.get 'r1', ['c1', 'c2']
  hbase> t.get 'r1', {CONSISTENCY => 'TIMELINE'}
  hbase> t.get 'r1', {CONSISTENCY => 'TIMELINE', REGION_REPLICA_ID => 1}
EOF
      end

      def command(table, row, *args)
        get(table(table), row, *args)
      end

      def get(table, row, *args)
        @start_time = Time.now
        formatter.header(["COLUMN", "CELL"])

        count, is_stale = table._get_internal(row, *args) do |column, value|
          formatter.row([ column, value ])
        end

        formatter.footer(count, is_stale)
      end
    end
  end
end

#add get command to table
::Hbase::Table.add_shell_command('get')
```

if you want to get one record similarly like hbase shell command, you can follow below snippet.

#### Update based on your comment : if you want to have same functionality in java

```
 /**
     * Get a row
     */
    @Override
    public void getOneRecord(final String tableName, final String rowKey) throws IOException {
        final HTable table = new HTable(HBaseConn.getHBaseConfig(), getTable(tableName));
        final Get get = new Get(rowKey.getBytes());
        final Result rs = table.get(get);
        for (final KeyValue kv : rs.raw()) {
            LOG.info(kv.getRow() + " " + kv.getFamily() + ":" + kv.getQualifier() + " " + +kv.getTimestamp());
            LOG.info(new String(kv.getValue()));
        }
    }
```

#### Note : There java approach and shell approach are 2 different things. pls. don't **mix both,** as [I have seen your other questions as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258139/how-to-use-java-api-to-send-hbase-shell-command-directly-like-jdbc/39268032#39268032), I think you are bit confused about them. If you want to write jruby just like I explained you can also do as well. but that was not common approach.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to overwrite "hbase shell command" by **Java**, then I can send "hbase shell command" directly in Java project. how to do? Like this: `public static void main(String args[]) {`
    `// get Connection to connect hbase`
    `Connection conn = ....;`
    `// hbase shell command`
    `String cmd = "get 't1','r1'";`

    `ResultSet rs = conn.execute(cmd);`
`}`

Comment: what is your requirement, why you wanted to do that ?

Comment: I want to develop a WEB UI using Java or JSP, and I can send "hbase shell command" by WEB UI.

Comment: as I mentioned below you can execute through `Runtime`  class or `ProcessBuilder` class to invoke hbase shell and executing the command. But you asked for internal working of get command I gave. see my answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866640/execute-spark-submit-programmatically-from-java?noredirect=1&lq=1 to execute a shell command(either shell script or hbase shell <command> ). Hope this time you wont get confused :-)

Comment: I was just thinking why you need to integrate jsp + hbase shell command as web ui ? if you want to display results of Hbase there are several other ways to do it like solr + solrj can render results to REST api? Is there any valid reason for that ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment and your patience!