# my Java command Process builder never exit

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm trying to run a command in my java program that allows me to use the external software ffmpeg to extract subtitles from a video file.

On my cmd the command works fine, but when I run it from my IDE from a process builder, it executes but never finishes.

It's only when I stop my application that the subtitle file appears in the specified folder, which means that the command executes correctly but never stops.

can anyone help?

here's some code to illustrate what I mean

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
        command.add("ffmpeg");
        command.add("-i");
        command.add(fileName);
        command.add("-c:s");
        command.add("srt");
        command.add(subfile);

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command(command);

processBuilder.directory(new File(UPLOAD_MOVIE_DIR_disc + movie.getTitle() ));

processConvert.waitFor(); //never finish
```

by the time I got an answer, I had to use a new thread next to it, which would stop the process execution after a while, but this is not suitable for an application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [process.waitFor() never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns)

Comment: Note how the answer talks about that you need to consume the output somehow or the program won't quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is related to how you're handling the process output streams. By default, `ProcessBuilder` uses pipes for communication, which can cause the `waitFor()` method to hang indefinitely if the streams aren't drained.

you can fix your code by redirect standard error or  using process streams

Comment: you r right StreamGobbler can do this and solve my problem thank you !

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you calling? Where did processConvert come from?

ProcessBuilder.waitFor() does not exist.
You need to start your process using ProcessBuilder.start(), then use waitFor() on the created process. While doing that you need to drain the output buffers (the processes STDOUT and STDERR streams).

So use waitFor() only in case you have other threads taking care to drain the buffers.

Comment: it's obvious but I didn't specify it sorry